# Search Git remote all branches for file contents

Tags: git, github

Is it possible to search all of my Git remote branches for specific file contents (not just a file, but contents within them)?

My remotes are on GitHub, in case that helps...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can try this:

```
git grep 'search-string' $(git ls-remote . 'refs/remotes/*' | cut -f 2)
```

That will search all remote branches for `search-string`.  Since the symbolic reference `HEAD` is mirrored, you may end up searching the same commit twice.  Hopefully that's not an issue.  If so, you can filter it out with:

```
git grep 'search-string' \
    $(git ls-remote . 'refs/remotes/*' | grep -v HEAD | cut -f 2)
```

If you need to dig through your entire history, you can also try:

```
git grep 'search-string' $(git rev-list --all)
```

Comment: Second command works for me, but the first doesn't; I get `fatal: bad flag '->' used after filename`

Comment: Sorry about that.  I forgot that `git branch -r` will show the contents of symbolic refs in it.  I've updated my answer with something else that works, but not quite as pretty.

Answer (score 6):

**Assuming you are tracking all remote branches**, this will search it in all commits:

```
git log --all -p | grep 'search-string'
```

**To track all remote branches:**

```
for remote in `git branch -r`; do git branch --track $remote; done
```

Comment: how is it helpful in learning where output lines are located (branch / file)?