# How do I search for specific code in a specific branch in a Github repository?

Tags: github

I've tried to use the advanced search feature of Github, but when I search `"specific text" repo:company/project/tree/specific_branch` it does not return the desired results.  It only seems to search master branch.

Comment: How's your problem? Did the answer help?

Comment: @NickVolynkin Your answer didn't help me.  Ended up searching manually for what I was looking for.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Searching code in a specific GitHub branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31891733/searching-code-in-a-specific-github-branch)

Answer (score 6):

I too was looking for this. but this support in not available as per github help.

> Due to the complexity of searching code, there are a few restrictions on how searches are performed:
>
> Only the default branch is considered. In most cases, this will be the master branch.
>   Only files smaller than 384 KB are searchable.
>   Only repositories with fewer than 500,000 files are searchable.

Answer (score 4):

**Update:** There's [Hubscovery](https://github.com/jschoolcraft/Hubscovery) which probably solves the problem.

I understand that you've been asking about a way to use GitHub's own tools to do the search. After a brief overview I could not find a solution there.

But any GitHub repo is a Git repo. So you are free to use the power of console commands. There's a [git grep](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-grep) command, allowing you to search for lines matching a pattern throughout the repository.

```
git grep 'search-string' $(git ls-remote . 'refs/remotes/remote_name/branch_to_search_in' | cut -f 2)
```

Instead of `remote_name/branch_to_search_in` put the actual names of remote and branch.

This example is based on the code from other [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18278774/search-git-remote-all-branches-for-file-contents).

Comment: Does a clone needed? Can it be done using a "shallow clone"? I think the asker is asking to invoke search specifically on github's server - without needing to clone the repo. If the repo is cloned, why search the server?