# Searching code in a specific GitHub branch

Tags: git, github

I am trying to search some code in a branch in a GitHub repository.

However [this](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-code/) indicates that I can only search the default branch.

Is there a way I can search code in non-default branch in my GitHub repository?

Comment: Perhaps using API. So far no option to search code in specific branch. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30221643/how-do-i-search-for-specific-code-in-a-specific-branch-in-a-github-repository)

Answer (score 131, accepted):

Not from the GitHub web interface itself, as mentioned in "[How can I search for a commit message on GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18122628/how-to-search-for-a-commit-message-on-github/28493853#28493853)": only the [default branch](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-the-default-branch/) (generally `master`) is indexed.

Your best bet is to clone the repository, and there, search in all branches (with [`git log -S` for instance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2928721/6309)).

Comment: Ive been needing this for a while, and this post gave me a lightbulb.  Fork the code, in the settings of your repo, set the branch to what you want.  WIN

Comment: As @cgmckeever has no doubt discovered, you can not search a forked repo, even if you set the default branch to the branch you want to search. "Sorry, forked repositories are not currently searchable"

Comment: actually, if you fork, and then push your branch into a new repo, it is, as that new repo gets indexes

Comment: @cgmckeever fork in on the server side (GitHub). You don't need to fork. You need to clone, and then push to a new empty remote GitHub repo. Then yes, that new repo will be indexed (only its master branch though)

Comment: GitHub does not index `master`, it does indexation on the **DEFAULT** branch which could be a release branch behind master/devel branch...

Comment: @Mizux Thank you. I have edited the answer accordingly. Do you have any reference documenting that policy?

Comment: just my own experiment when we change the default branch here https://github.com/google/or-tools since we use master as a devel branch but we want user to see last stable release... some API are on master not on default (stable branch) and the contrary, search only found api symbols in stable branch

Answer (score 46):

If you want to search in a specific branch, first set the branch by selecting it on the project main page. Then, hit the period (`.`) key on your keyboard. This will open up the project in an online VS Code editor.
From there, you can use the sidebar on the left to search code or view files directly. Preferably using the Search (magnifying glass-icon) functionality to search across the whole project.

More details on GitHub Codespaces and using the web-based editor can be found [here](https://docs.github.com/en/codespaces/the-githubdev-web-based-editor#opening-the-githubdev-editor).

Comment: this should be the preferred answer, since the OP obviously wants to search online

Comment: Doesn't work for me in a corporate github (url isn't `github.com/...`, it's `github.someCorpName.com`)

Answer (score 29):

Using console, I would search for specific code in a specific branch with the following

```
git grep 'my_search_text' my_branch
```

- `my_branch` should be available locally
- `git grep` can perform pattern matching of high complexity ([see the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-grep))

Answer (score 8):

If you know the **filename** you can use `Find File`.

[image]

[image]

https://github.com/angular/angular/find/6.1.x

Comment: oh boy - they really need to do something about HighDPI screenshots :-/ sorry!

Comment: Not too helpful if we wanted just search a specific file, could already do that in any ide.

Comment: @wanna_coder101 when I'm looking for something I usually don't have the repo locally (trying to diagnose a bug or something in someone elses code), but yes point taken :-)

Answer (score 7):

With a GitHub account, you can use GitHub online editor (**github.dev** [1](https://docs.github.com/en/codespaces/the-githubdev-web-based-editor#opening-the-githubdev-editor), hotkey: open a repo page and press `.` on the keyboard) to open the branch of a repository and search for your keywords.

Example: how to find "useMeta" keyword in [github.com/nuxt/vue-meta](https://github.com/nuxt/vue-meta) `next` branch?

This keyword is expected to be not in the default `master` branch, but in `next` branch. Here is how you can find it in the desired branch:

1 open the repo page and *choose the branch*. eg https://github.com/nuxt/vue-meta/tree/next

2 start GitHub online editor by press `.`

don't forget to log in GitHub first.

the online code editor url looks like https://github.dev/nuxt/vue-meta/tree/next

3 enter your keyword "useMeta" in the Search function on the code editor sidebar

4 check the result: this keyword exists in `next` branch ✅

5 in the repo page, choose `master` branch, enter online code editor by press `.`, search for the keyword with Search function on the sidebar, and you see that the keyword is not found in that branch.

Comment: This is the way.

Comment: Working exactly as explained.