# Github pages: Why do I need a gh-pages

Tags: jekyll, jekyll-extensions, jekyll-bootstrap, jekyll-paginator

I have deployed a personal blog using Github pages and I see that some tutorials tell you to create a gh-pages branch. I did that, however, my changes to the website are visible only if I make changes to my master. So, I'm confused as to why I need gh-pages? Can someone please explain this. Thanks

Answer (score 17):

You no longer need a `gh-pages` branch. [GitHub now allows pages to be published from the master `branch`, or from a `docs` folder in master.](https://github.com/blog/2228-simpler-github-pages-publishing)

[image: Now you can select a source in your repository settings and GitHub Pages will look for your content there.]

Comment: Would there be any reason to still use `gh-pages`, or is it now recommended to just use the `master` branch? It is considered better code organization to keep your website code in a separate, or is it simply unnecessary?

Comment: Assuming I create a new repo and crete a `/docs` folder within it. I upload a static site on the docs folder and point the source to it. In this scenario, what is the use of master then?

Comment: @TotZam: I haven't seen good reasons to keep the documentation in a separate branch. On the contrary, [GitHub only searches in the default branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31891733/searching-code-in-a-specific-github-branch), so you make it extra hard for contributors to contribute PRs to your documentation.

Answer (score 4):

**You host one website per github person or organization on the master branch. This is used for a personal website or organization website.**

Such a personal or organization site is hosted on username.github.io in a dedicated repo in the master branch.

My personal blog for example is on [takacsmark.github.io](http://takacsmark.github.io), it is hosted in a repo called https://github.com/takacsmark/takacsmark.github.io, the code is in the master branch of the repo and [takacsmark.com](http://takacsmark.com) is pointed to this site via the CNAME file in the repo.

**In case you want to create a dedicated site for a project on github, you can create a project level github page.** This means that it is not a separate repo, like the personal website example above. **Instead, it should be under the gh-pages branch of the project repo.**

Check out the [bootstrap repo](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/tree/gh-pages) for a project gh-pages example.

Comment: GitHub Pages should really make this distinction in [their docs](https://help.github.com/categories/github-pages-basics/) about this. When one considers setting up a GitHub Pages repo to go with a project vs. a whole personal site as the project, the `gh-pages` branch makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

There can be two types of pages on GitHub. The first type has the files in the `master` branch and the repo has to be named the same way as the `<username|organization>.github.{io|com}`. There can be only one repository of this type.

The url of the pages is: `http://<username|organization>.github.io` or `.com`

The second type of pages doesn't put any restriction to the repository name, but the pages need to be in the `gh-pages` branch.

The url of the pages is: `http://<username|organization>.github.io/<repo_name>` or `.com`

More details [here](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages/).

Comment: Yes, but what is the gh-pages used for?

Comment: I think, it's obvious, from the answer. Provided you are hosting your blog on the first type of pages (`http://<username|organization>.github.io`), there is no point in creating `gh-pages` and all the jekyll code, or plain html goes into `master`. It's vice versa if you are doing the second type of pages.

Comment: So, if I wanted to get a domain name (i.e. mydomain.com) I cannot use that on the master branch becuase the remo needs to be username.github.io ? I need to have a gh-pages for that reason? Am i understanding that correctly?

Comment: No, what, I've described is the default behavior. The default URLs where GitHub makes your content available. You can change that by providing a `CNAME` file and have the DNS set up correctly https://help.github.com/articles/quick-start-setting-up-a-custom-domain