# How do I search for a word within repository?

Tags: github

For e.g. I am looking for all the words "import" and I can use the search box that returns something like this...

https://github.com/charlesdaniel/s3_uploader/search?l=python&q=import&utf8=%E2%9C%93

This lists only 8 results for s3_uploader.py file. When I checked the file, there are 12 import statements, some of those are not returned in the search. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This lists only 8 results for s3_uploader.py file. When I checked the file, there are 12 import statements

Not exactly: it shows the *top* height results

[image]

That means it isn't meant to reflect the accurate number of occurrences, but rather indicate the most prominent ones.

Comment: Is there any other way to return all results from a repository?

Comment: @shantanuo Not without cloning the repo first, and then running a git grep (as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/18279145/6309 for instance)